# Maven, Webstart, and Java 8 Headaches

Tags: java, maven, mojo

I am trying to convert a project from compiling with Java 6 to Java 8.  We are using the webstart-maven-plugin for which there is currently a workaround (http://mojo.10943.n7.nabble.com/jira-MWEBSTART-269-Java-8-support-td44357.html) for compiling with Java 8 by adding the following dependencies to the plugin definition.

```
...
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>webstart-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>webstart-pack200-impl</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>keytool-api-1.7</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                ...
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
...
```

This got me past my initial issues.

I am now receiving the following error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:webstart-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-6:jnlp-inline (default) on project <redacted>: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.codehaus.mojo:webstart-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-6:jnlp-inline for parameter pack200: Cannot find default setter in class org.codehaus.mojo.webstart.Pack200Config -> [Help 1]
```

The Help link goes to the following page.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginConfigurationException

As far as I can figure out, the webstart-pack200-impl dependency requires some configuration to define which setter is used.  Any information regarding setters that I have found online seems to be a different issue from this.  I can't figure out if there is a way to set a configuration for a dependency.

Or am I looking at this in a completely incorrect way?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: As a note, with beta-7 you shouldn't need to add those dependencies anymore...unless you *do* want it to pack200 in which case you'll need the webstart-pack200-impl dependency.

Answer (score 7):

the error points to pack200 which was configured as `<pack200>false</pack200>`in older version of webstart plugin configuration.

This can be resolved by changing pack200 configuration to this instead (within `<configuration>` section of the plugin settings)

```
<pack200><enabled>false</enabled></pack200>
```

for more details please refer http://www.mojohaus.org/webstart/webstart-maven-plugin/upgrade.html section "Important changes since 1.0-beta-3"